# Read memory of 64bit process address

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I try to read memory at address of a process
that's the code :

```
std::cout << "Found Process " << procEntry32.szExeFile << " With process ID " << procEntry32.th32ProcessID << std::endl;
hProc == OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procEntry32.th32ProcessID);
pID = procEntry32.th32ProcessID;

if (hProc == NULL) {
    std::cout << "failed getting  handle" << std::endl;
}

CloseHandle(hProcSnap);
std::cout << "hProcSnap handle closed ... " << std::endl;
return true;
```

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M5P9.png)

I use DWORD64

This code works if I try to read a 32-Bit process but with 64-Bit I get error

Comment: My guess would be, it's not about 32-bit vs 64-bit. Rather, the process for which this fails runs under a different user account, or same user but elevated, and so your program doesn't have sufficcient privileges to obtain `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` handle. Check `GetLastError()` after the failed `OpenAccess` call - I bet it's `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: Don't forget to run you code as Administrator.

Comment: No proper error checking, no answer

Answer (score -1):

This can help you : [read_memory.cpp](https://github.com/MatthieuHernandez/LightPunchBot/blob/master/AI/environnement/read_memory.cpp#L79)

This is a personal project where I had read in the memory of a video game.

**Update**

```
bool Read_memory::initialize()
{
    string name = Thread::instance()->read("window_name");
    wstring name1(name.begin(), name.end());
    const wchar_t* name2 = name1.c_str();
    LPCTSTR window_name = name2;
    BOOL is_64bits;
    DWORD process_id;
    SYSTEM_INFO system_information;
    GetSystemInfo(&system_information);//GetSystemInfo at 32 bit
    hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, window_name);
    Thread::instance()->write("Information system found !", "console");
    proc_min_address = (int64_t) system_information.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    first_address = proc_min_address;
    proc_max_address = (int64_t) system_information.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
    if(!hwnd)
    {
        Thread::instance()->write("Window not found !", "console");
        return false;
    }
    Thread::instance()->write("Window found", "console");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &process_id);
    Thread::instance()->write((string)"process : " + std::to_string(process_id), "console");
    if(true)
    {
        if(true/*error == "5"*/)
        {
            if(!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, &handle_token))
            {
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
                {
                    if (!ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation))
                    {
                        Thread::instance()->write("ERROR 1 !!!", "console");
                        return false;
                    }

                    if(!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, &handle_token))
                    {
                        Thread::instance()->write("ERROR 2 !!!", "console");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread::instance()->write("ERROR 3 !!!", "console");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (!SetPrivilege(handle_token, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE))
            {
                Thread::instance()->write((string)"error : " + std::to_string(GetLastError()), "console");
                Thread::instance()->write("Error in AdjustTokenPrivileges", "console");
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
                Thread::instance()->write("Privilege modify", "console");

        }
        else
        {
            Thread::instance()->write((string)"error : " + std::to_string(GetLastError()), "console");
            return false;
        }
    }
    handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, process_id);
    if(!handle)
    {
        Thread::instance()->write((string)"error : " + std::to_string(GetLastError()), "console");
        Thread::instance()->write("SHIT !!!", "console");
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(handle_token);
    if(!IsWow64Process(handle, &is_64bits))
    {
        string error = (string)std::to_string(GetLastError());
        Thread::instance()->write("Could not use 64 bits process !", "console");
        Thread::instance()->write(error, "console");
        return false;
    }
    Thread::instance()->write("Use 32 bits process !", "console");
    Thread::instance()->write("Get handle !", "console");

    Thread::instance()->write((string)"Size of : " + std::to_string(sizeof(int64_t)), "console"); // 2^16
    Thread::instance()->write((string)"Min : " + std::to_string(proc_min_address), "console"); // 2^16
    Thread::instance()->write((string)"Max : " + std::to_string(proc_max_address), "console"); // 2^31 - 2^16
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Be more specific which part of the code give example

Comment: Look at the method `Read_memory::initialize()` line 79

Comment: Please don't link code like this. Please post relevant parts of it here.